# Reasons why git is not visible to Rstudio (OSX)

Tags: macos, git, github, rstudio

I have been trying for a few hours to use git within Rstudio on my macbook. However, the option to use git within version control is missing - the only option remains (none).

- I have installed github, and then git directly, using the link given
  in the rstudio website.
- I have attempted to run the bash script
  supplied with the git installation file.
- I have verified that git is
  active on the machine through both github and directly through the
  command line.
- I have located the git file in the hidden folder

  /local/git/bin/git

and pointed Rstudio to this using global options.

- I have reinstalled git a couple of times.
- I have logged off and on again multiple times.

Any solutions very welcome.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now working. As expected it took re-installing the operating system, as well as the following:
http://blog.rstudio.org/2013/10/22/rstudio-and-os-x-10-9-mavericks/

Using the preview version available from the link below solved the Rstudio/Git issue instantly.

Answer (score 10):

The same just happened on my mac.  I narrowed down the issue to the Xcode developers package update.  The fix in my case was:

- From a shell go to /usr/bin
- sudo ./git
- Agree to the terms
- Close and reopen RStudio

Voilà. Git has returned to RStudio.

Comment: This produced an error for me `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path`. Solution that worked for me explained in answer below (too long for comment, and addresses different issue)

Comment: On Mac 14.2.1 I followed instructions at this link. I only got as far as `git status` and the problem was solved. https://happygitwithr.com/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 6):

My RStudio git tab disappeared after upgrading to OS X El Capitan. I tried following the advice in the top answer:

but I got the error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

which led me to discover I had to reinstall XCode command-line tools. I did this via:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I also updated to latest release of RStudio. Then my git tab reappeared.

Comment: In 2022, this worked after I upgraded to macOS Ventura 13.0

Answer (score 4):

I just came across your question after I encountered a similar issue on windows. You've probably sorted yourself by now but just to let you & others know what worked for me.

- From RStudio Tools, Global Options.
- Option for Git Executable.
- Browsed to git.exe in the git/bin folder.

Now working like a dream.
Andy

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach too. It's a bit trickier with OS-X as the relevant files are hidden and Shift+cmd+. is needed to reveal them. However even when set to the correct location in RStudio it still complains that the program cannot be found and the 'git' version control option remains unavailable. 
I think I've got a particularly strangely configured Macbook - I'm the second 'owner' and don't think it was rebuilt correctly. Looking forward to trying it on Windows when hopefully it should work a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with OSX High Sierra
[This answer in this thread on GitHub helped me](https://github.com/jennybc/happy-git-with-r/issues/8#issuecomment-257991250)

In short, OSX seems to use another directory for the git file